# 'Considered' vs 'Considered as'

Tags: grammaticality

I would like to know which one of the following is correct:

> **Sentence #1:**
>   This job is considered a dream job.
>
> **Sentence #2:**
>   This job is considered as a dream job.

I can recall that when I was in 9th grade one of my English language teachers told me that the sentence #2 is not correct.

That means ***as*** should be omitted after the word **considered** in this case.

Comment: I don't think the second setence is good, but you can use as after considered in some cases, e.g.: _This car is considered as good as a Ferrari_

Comment: Yes you are right. ***But the people around me have been, in fact always,  using the second one for years***.

Comment: You can also say "This job is considered **to be** a dream job."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example, when two things are compared to be equal (this job == dream job), "as" is indeed not necessary. However, it would be wrong to state that "as" should be omitted after "consider" altogether, because it can be used in other contexts:

> The tool A was used as a solution to the problem. We suggest tool B to be **considered as** another approach to solving the problem.

Answer (score 1):

After searching the corpus (millions of English texts), "considered as" (3,000) is significantly less used when compared to just "considered" (108,000). 3,000 uses is not insignificant, so it is difficult to say that it is necessarily "incorrect".

I found some theoretical grammar difference, but it is largely not observed and writers often seem to use "considered as" as just another alternative to "considered".

---

The theory:

**Considered + object**

Used when the subject should be just another name for something. Literally, that the object is the subject.

> He should be considered our leader since he makes all the decisions.

= He is our leader.

**Considered + as + object**

Used when the object can be used to replace the subject.

> Indoor soccer should be considered as an alternative to outdoor soccer in winter.

= The two are equally good